# FlatFileParseException while parsing csv file to dump data in MySQL using Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to dump data from csv to MySQL using Spring Batch. But on running the application, the following error is encountered:

```
org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException: Parsing error at line: 2 in resource=[class path resource [People2.csv]], input=[aardsda01,1981,12,27,USA,CO,Denver,2022,2,22,USA,NJ,Atlanta,David,Aardsma,David Allan,215,75,R,R,06-04-2004,23-08-2015,aardd001,aardsda01]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:194) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:95) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:110) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:189) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:137) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    
...............
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.IncorrectTokenCountException: Incorrect number of tokens found in record: expected 24 actual 7
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.AbstractLineTokenizer.tokenize(AbstractLineTokenizer.java:133) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper.mapLine(DefaultLineMapper.java:42) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:190) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

The ItemReader and ItemWriter Beans are:

```
@Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Player> reader()
    {
        
        
        FlatFileItemReader<Player> reader=new FlatFileItemReader<Player>();
        
        
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("People2.csv"));
        reader.setLineMapper(getLineMapper());
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1);//Skip line in case of error
        return reader;
    }

    private LineMapper<Player> getLineMapper() {
        
        DefaultLineMapper<Player> lineMapper
=new DefaultLineMapper<Player>();
        
        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer=new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        
        lineTokenizer.setNames(new String[] {"playerID","birthYear","","","","","birthCity","","","","","","","nameFirst","nameLast","","","","","","","","retroID","bbrefID"});//name of field to be taken out. Empty string are columns which has to be skipped 
        lineTokenizer.setIncludedFields(new int[] {0,1,6,13,14,22,23});
        
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Player> fieldSetMapper=new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Player>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(Player.class);
        
        
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
        
        return lineMapper;
    }
```

Spring Boot version I am using is 3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

`Incorrect number of tokens found in record: expected 24 actual 7` means you have less tokens in your input line than it is expected by your batch job.

In fact, you declared 24 names in `lineTokenizer.setNames`, but only included 7 in `lineTokenizer.setIncludedFields`. Those two parameters should match. You should think of it like: "Please include only these fields, and here are their names".

If you remove those empty `""` (no need for them) and your input line has exactly 7 columns, then this error should not happen.

Comment: Is it possible to include only specific columns from the input file and leave the rest ? Like there 24 columns in the input file but I want only 7 of them in the database.

Comment: yes, once you map data to your domain class, you can choose which fields to write in the database in your item writer.